# how to understand "getting drawn into it despite myself"?

Tags: sentence-structure, phrases

An excerpt from "Elba" by Marly Swick:

> "She didn't mention any husband at all," I said, **getting drawn into it despite myself**.

the Dic says "draw into" means "to involve someone in a conversation or situation, often when they do not want to be involved." So here does it mean that the author is unwilling to be involved in the conversation she has with her mom?
And the phrase "despite myself" really eludes me, does that mean "despite the fact that I don't want to get drawn into it"?

Comment: Yes, you've got the meanings right. He joined the conversation unwillingly, or unintentionally, or without meaning to, or against his better judgement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**Getting drawn into**" something means that you have been influenced to become involved in a matter, perhaps one that you did not want to be part of.

"**Despite myself**" is similar to other expressions such as "despite my better judgement". It means that you did something contrary to your best thoughts and feelings on the matter.

In your example, the first person is clearly responding to the mention of someone's husband. By responding to this they have now involved themselves in the conversation. By adding "*...getting drawn into it despite myself*" they acknowledge in the narrative that they have become involved, even though they did not want to.